# Looping on variables with a condition in bash (Stopping services in a specific order)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a script in bash to perform the below use cases,

- Finding specific services based on specific words on their names
- Stopping these services **in a specific order like: service_1, service_2 and so on**
- Checking if these services are stopped and **if there is a one that is still up & running, It will print out it's name**

This is my progress,
Firstly, I've found the services based on some words that only exists with their names as below,

```
service_1=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_2=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text2 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_3=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text3 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
```

Then, I've stopped them in the order i want as below:

```
if [ ! -z "$service_1" ] //if service exists
then
      systemctl stop $service_1
else
      :
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] //if service exists
then
      systemctl stop $service_2
else
      :
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_3" ] //if service exists
then
      systemctl stop $service_3
else
      :
fi
```

Here comes the problem. As you know, when stopping a service, it may take some time to be fully stopped so as per the conditions above it will move forward in stopping the second service without full stopping the previous one. What I want is stopping the services in order so before stopping the second service the first one should be fully stopped and so on. How to make that ? I think this can be made by loops but I am missing the way.
Regarding the third use case, I've defined the below variables that holds the word "inactive" after filtering the status output of the services as an indicator that the services are stopped:

```
service_1_status=$(systemctl status $service_1 | grep -e "inactive")
service_2_status=$(systemctl status $service_2 | grep -e "inactive")
service_3_status=$(systemctl status $service_3 | grep -e "inactive")
```

Then, I've tried to loop on them to find out if there is a service that is still active to print it's name as below:

```
arr=($service_1_status $service_2_status $service_3_status $service_q_inf_status)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
      if "${arr[$i}" != "inactive"
      then
            echo $i
      else
            echo "All Services are now Stopped"
      fi
done
```

I don't know if this syntax if fully operational or not as it doesn't work but this is the logic I want to do. What is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `grep -e text1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`, just use `awk '/text1/{print $1}'`

Comment: [Parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is an anti-pattern. Instead of `ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1` just use `ls /etc/systemd/system/*text1*`. That would still leave you piping the `ls` output to awk though which is still an anti-pattern - show us some sample contents of the `/etc/systemd/system` directory so we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: You can use `systemctl is-active` to know if a server is up or down.  `--wait` will wait for the stop to complete before moving on.  Check the man page for caveats on `--wait`.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell for your input, It really saves much effort.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500, I've also found some helpful options that can manage the ordering of starting/stopping services like `--after` & `--before`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Service variables.

service_1=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1 | \
awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')

service_2=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text2 | \
awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')

service_3=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text3 | \
awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')

# Service stopping code.

[[ -n "${service_1}" ]] && systemctl stop "{$service_1}"
[[ -n "${service_2}" ]] && systemctl stop "{$service_2}"
[[ -n "${service_3}" ]] && systemctl stop "{$service_3}"


service_1_status=$(systemctl status $service_1 | grep -e "inactive")
service_2_status=$(systemctl status $service_2 | grep -e "inactive")
service_3_status=$(systemctl status $service_3 | grep -e "inactive")

[[ -n "${service_1_status}" ]] && \
[[ -n "${service_2_status}" ]] && \
[[ -n "${service_3_status}" ]] && \
echo "All services stopped."
```

This is a 3 input test.  It will only pass if all three variables equal inactive.

Comment: This will only stop the services and then check that they are stopped but won't do that in a specific order as mentioned, I want to make sure that service_1 is fully stopped before proceeding with service_2 and "systemctl stop" will just trigger the action but not waiting till the service is fully stopped.

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux, use "ps -ef | grep ${servicename}" to check whether or not it is still running.

Comment: What if it's still running ?, I want to make it wait till the previous service is fully stopped then retry to stop the service again (If service_1 is still active, Wait till it becomes inactive then try to start service_2 again), That's the behavior i want to do, I think this should be made using a loop with a condition to handle the second part of the main condition (Checking if the service is inactive or not).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried also my suggested approach and it works.

Comment: I was initially going to suggest a sleep, which I see you've used; but you will still need to actually check if the process is running or not.

Comment: That's what i've done in my approach, After forcing the process to wait for a 30s, I'm checking in the next condition if the previous service exists and active or not before proceeding with next one and if it is inactive or failed, The script will stop execution and exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

service_1=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_2=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text2 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_3=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text3 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')

if [ ! -z "$service_1" ] # if service exists
then
      systemctl start $service_1
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_1 started"
else
      :
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_1" ] # if service exists
then
      if [ $(systemctl is-active $service_1) == "active" ] # if service is active
      then
            if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] # if service exists
            then
                  systemctl start $service_2
                  sleep 30 # 30s
                  echo "$service_2 started"
            else
                  :
            fi
      else
      echo "$service_1 is either inactive or failed, Please check !"
      exit
      fi
elif [ ! -z "$service_2" ]
then
      systemctl start $service_2
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_2 started"
else
:
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] # if service exists
then
      if [ $(systemctl is-active $service_2) == "active" ] # if service is active
      then
            if [ ! -z "$service_3" ] # if service exists
            then
                  systemctl start $service_3
                  sleep 30 # 30s
                  echo "$service_3 started"
            else
                  :
            fi
      else
      echo "$service_2 is either inactive or failed, Please check !"
      exit
      fi
elif [ ! -z "$service_3" ]
then
      systemctl start $service_3
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_3 started"
else
:
fi`enter code here`
```